# Python library to solve nonlinear problems

Tags: python, nonlinear-programming

What is the best python library to solve nonlinear problems? PuLP can solve only linear problems like $\max15000Z_7 + 350D_{73}Z_7 - 15000Z_8 + 350D_{86}Z_8$.

Comment: Hi Karim, have you considered Pyomo + IPOPT? There are a few questions about Pyomo and IPOPT, see for instance: [NLP solvers in Pyomo other than IPOPT?](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1032/nlp-solvers-in-pyomo-other-than-ipopt?rq=1)

Comment: Hi Stefano, I tried to install pyomo but jupyter always sends this (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyomo'). I installed it using pip install pyomo

Comment: Hi Karim, you can find instructions about using Pyomo+IPOPT on a Google Colab (similar to Jupyter notebook) at this answer: [How to install IPOPT on Google Colab for Pyomo](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/7145/how-to-install-ipopt-on-google-colab-for-pyomo/7173#7173)

Comment: Another way to use Ipopt from Python is [cyipopt](https://cyipopt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: Checkout cvxopt, It provides you with a good interface for convex problems. Some examples are available [here](http://cvxopt.org/examples/index.html)

Comment: Ok, I will try it again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find [non-linear solver binaries here](https://ampl.com/products/solvers/open-source/). Also for academic purpose you can use [SCIP](https://www.scipopt.org/) which is very good. For modelling interface, SCIP has own python [interface](https://github.com/scipopt/PySCIPOpt). Or you can use PYOMO for all of them with jupyter notebook. (I think you have installation problem). Or you can use Google OR-TOOLS but I don't know which solvers supported except SCIP.